# Php, Laravel - search array with wildcard key and return array results

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

php:

```
$getallvalues
```

Gives me the array from session:

```
array:7 [▼
  "_token" => "ZCP63uasUQHl948oVVDG7ZO4x33"
  "_previous" => array:1 [▶]
  "flash" => array:2 [▶]
  "key1" => "1"
  "key2" => "2"
  "id-2" => "2"
  "id-3" => "3"
]
```

How to retrieve a new one array with wildcard key "id-" to give me the result:

```
 array:2 [▼
      "id-2" => "2"
      "id-3" => "3"
    ]
```

I tryed some php methods like: array_values, in_array etc but nothing works as I expected.

Comment: See this [https://glot.io/snippets/eew9bqe5hb](https://glot.io/snippets/eew9bqe5hb)

Comment: @GarvitMangal You can improve your answer using `array_intersect_key` instead of the foreach loop

Comment: @Scopey Thank you for pointing me at that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Php Search\_Array using Wildcard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592120/php-search-array-using-wildcard)

Answer (score 1):

I found a better solution without foreach code in 2 lines only!!

```
$resultsession = preg_grep('/^id-[\d]*/', array_keys($getallsession));
$result = array_flip($resultsession);
```