# How to SUM items that I don´t know the name?

Tags: php, laravel, sum

I have this return $request on my Laravel app. This code is the exactly from 'return $request;' command.

This is from Controller

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
    return $request; 
}
```

And this is the print on the view.blade. It is quite different from yours that has:

```
$jsonList = '{ 
    "_method": "POST",
    "_token": null,
    "cliente": "2",
    "nrocpfCnpj": "00635344000177",
    "originalSegmento": "4",
    "example_length": "10",
    "cota853": "12975",
    "cota835": "11945",
    "cota209": "12110",
    "cota501": "12110"
}
```

And mine:

```
{
    "_method": "POST",
    "_token": null,
    "cliente": "2",
    "nrocpfCnpj": "00635344000177",
    "originalSegmento": "4",
    "example_length": "10",
    "cota853": "12975",
    "cota835": "11945",
    "cota209": "12110",
    "cota501": "12110"
    }
```

I need to SUM each cota, but it is always variable, so I will never get the name so I can do the math.
How do You guys would do it?

Any hints?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Php, Laravel - search array with wildcard key and return array results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37367630/php-laravel-search-array-with-wildcard-key-and-return-array-results)

Comment: following example above will solve your problem

Comment: Example given would solve your issue, if not solved please provide more information in your post for better responses.

Comment: Did you give up???

Comment: No, take a look at my own answer! Should I check my own answer to close it?

Answer (score 1):

Use `array_walk` and regular expression for selecting keys with words `cota`

```
$data = $request->all();

$sum = 0;

array_walk($data, function ($item, $key) use (&$sum){
    if (preg_match('/^cota*/', $key) === 1) {
        $sum += $item;
    }    
});

echo $sum;
```

Comment: Hi @potiev, thank for your help, but it didn´t work. 

```
array_walk() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given
```

Comment: Yeah, but doesn´t work for me! Why is that? Always get this error:
```ErrorException (E_WARNING)
array_walk() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given```

Answer (score 1):

If you know part of key

```php
$json = '{
"_method": "POST",
"_token": null,
"cliente": "2",
"nrocpfCnpj": "00635344000177",
"originalSegmento": "4",
"example_length": "10",
"cota853": "12975",
"cota835": "11945",
"cota209": "12110",
"cota501": "12110"
}';
$data = json_decode($json,true);

$keyPart = 'cota';

$filtered = array_filter($data, function($k) use($keyPart) {
    return strpos($k,$keyPart) === 0;
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
//[
//  'cota853' => "12975"
//  'cota835' => "11945"
//  'cota209' => "12110"
//  'cota501' => "12110"
//]

$sum = array_sum($filtered);
//49140
```

Comment: Then your json isn't valid

Comment: @MarcelloPatto try to look for error https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php

Comment: @Konorlevich, and guys. All your answers work now. But my total is different. It returns 49993 what it is obviously wrong. And I am using the same numbers! What could be?

Comment: @MarcelloPatto Can you debug filtering and calculation?

Comment: It is working now. I was passing a param named cota (don´t know why, really) and it was counting on the SUM.

Answer (score 1):

Filter the array based on key and then sum them:

```
$sum = array_sum(array_filter($request, function($k) {
                                            return strpos($k, 'cota') === 0;
                                        }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @potiev's answer but using strpos instead of regex. strpos() returns the offset where the string begins, or the boolean false.

```
$json = '{
    "_method": "POST",
    "_token": null,
    "cliente": "2",
    "nrocpfCnpj": "00635344000177",
    "originalSegmento": "4",
    "example_length": "10",
    "cota853": "12975",
    "cota835": "11945",
    "cota209": "12110",
    "cota501": "12110"
}';


$data = json_decode($json, true);
$sum = 0;

foreach($data as $key => $value){
    if(strpos($key, 'cota') !== false){
        $sum = $sum + $value; 
    }
}

echo $sum;
```

Comment: It gives me this error:
```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

Comment: Make sure your json data is decoded correctly. Tested and working on my end.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error.

```
$data = $request->all();
        $keyPart = 'cota';
        $filtered = array_filter($data, function ($k) use ($keyPart) {
            return strpos($k, $keyPart) === 0;
        }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
        return $filtered;
```

returns:

```
{
"cota": "853",
"cota853": "12975",
"cota835": "11945",
"cota209": "12110",
"cota501": "12110"
}
```

So, I am passing a key called cota with value 853. This is not wrong, but don´t need for the sum. So I ´ll not pass it anymore.

Thnks You alll guys!